# Access attribute properties as instance properties - is it possible?

Tags: c#, properties, attributes

For example, I have a class with a property and attributes:

```cs
[MyDisplay(Name = "Class name", Description = "Class description.")]
public class MyClass
{
    [MyDisplay(Name = "Property name", Description = "Property description.")]
    public int MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

I want to get the attribute values like

```cs
// Get type attribute...
string className = MyClass.Attributes.MyDisplay.Name;

// Get member attribute...
string propertyDescription =
    MyClass.Properties.MyProperty.Attributes.MyDisplay.Description;
```

How to get it? I want the code that automatically fill the additional fields of MyClass with attribute data. It seems to be very convenient to access to the attribute values like to the instance values - for bindings, etc.

The main complexity is to fill MyClass.Attributes and MyClass.Properties collections with objects with names the same as properties and attributes names. And so I think this collections must be static. And each object inside MyClass.Properties collection also must has Attributes collection (for example, MyProperty.Attributes) like MyClass.Attributes collection.

Comment: What do you mean by 'instance level attribute' ? How do you want to declare in your code?

Comment: Attribute 'Display' is not valid on MyClass. It is only valid on 'method, property, indexer, field, param' declarations. Or have you implemented your own Display attribute?

Comment: rene, it can be any valid attribute for a class. I changed its name for clarity.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve, but below code will make you an idea how to extract attribute data from your assembly at run-time. Please note that attribute data is per type declaration, not per instance of type.

```
    foreach (var type in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes())
    {
        // class attributes
        foreach (var typeAttr in type.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false))
        {
            Console.WriteLine(((DisplayAttribute)typeAttr).Name);
            Console.WriteLine(((DisplayAttribute)typeAttr).Description);
        }

        // members attributes
        foreach (var props in type.GetProperties())
        {
            foreach (var propsAttr in props.GetCustomAttributes(typeof(DisplayAttribute), false))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(((DisplayAttribute)propsAttr).Name);
                Console.WriteLine(((DisplayAttribute)propsAttr).Description);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Oh, I mistaked a little! So, I know how to get attributes and its properties. I just want to organize them as of type's field. I fixes my question for clarity.